# Print Remotely Tailed file on browser

Tags: java, jsp, shell, unix, servlets

I have to tail the log file on my remote linux machine and print that as output on browser continuously. I've managed to tail it using JSch and I'm curremtly printing the output as System out. I' using servlet for this right now (although client is pressing to use only jsp). The problem is that as soon as I try to print the tailed stream on browser, the  browser goes in a freezing state as if it's continuously  loading something(which it is!!). The sysout logs flawlessly print the tailed stream on console while browser is frozen. Here is my servlet

```
package sshUploader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Run several ssh commands in a single JSch session
 */
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Hashtable;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TailLogServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "This servlet tails the remote logs", urlPatterns = { "/TailLogServlet" })
public class TailLogServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TailLogServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            System.out.println("**************************ADI NEW*****************");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
              String user = <user>;            //CHANGE ME
              String host = <host>; //CHANGE ME
              String passwd = <pwd>;      //CHANGE ME
              int port = 22;    
              Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
              session.setPassword(passwd);

              Hashtable<String, String> hashtable  = new Hashtable<String, String>();
              hashtable.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
              session.setConfig(hashtable);

              session.connect();

              Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
              OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
              PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

              channel.connect();
              InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();

              ps.println("tail -f /home/LogFile.log");
              ps.close();

             // response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1);
              response.setContentType("text/html");

              /*Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
              String am_pm;
              int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
              int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
              int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
              if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
                am_pm = "AM";
              else
                am_pm = "PM";

              String CT = hour+":"+ minute +":"+ second +" "+ am_pm;*/

              PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (response.getOutputStream());//.getWriter();
              out.println("<html><head><title>GuestBookServlet</title></head>");
              out.println("<body>********************");

              int SIZE = 1024;
              byte[] tmp = new byte[SIZE];
              while (true)
              {
                 while (input.available() > 0)
                 {
                    int i = input.read(tmp, 0, SIZE);
                    if(i < 0)
                       break;
                     System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i)); // use document.write(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                   // System.out.println("******Adi i :"+i);
                    //out.println("Out by Adi i :"+i);
                   out.println(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                 }
                 if(!channel.isConnected())
                 {
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                 }
                 try
                 {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                 }
                 catch (Exception ee)
                 {
                 }
             }
              out.println("</body></html>");
              out.close();


              channel.disconnect();
              session.disconnect();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

}

This only gets stuck with printing of stream. If I try printing current time by continuously updating it, I'm able to. It reflects perfectly in the browser. Is there any way out for me?

**EDIT:**
OK, I've narrowed down to the

> root cause

. It's the

> infinite while loop

I'm applying here. This loop checks continuously if there is anything in the input stream from remote. So, sysouts are getting printed correctly but the out.write aren't. If I remove infinite while loop, one line get printed as that's the only thig in the remote input stream. Any ideas as to how can I get the output on browser inside infinite while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it after spending some time on it. Updating late here as was busy in client delivery. Here are the steps.
Prepared a servlet called TailLogServlet.java which has the code of tailing the remote logs.
Prepared a jsp called showTailLogs.jsp that calls this servlet through ajax every 2 seconds and print the response on browser. This calling is done in the *body onLoad* function of jsp.
Here is the servlet and jsp: 
**showTailLogs.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myStyle.css">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
                <title>Show Tail Logs</title>
                <script>
                        var binDone = false;
                        var lastUpdate = "Starting logs";
                        function tail2() {
                                if (!binDone) {
                                        $.post("/<<Context>>/TailLogServlet",
                                          {
                                                logUID:"<%= request.getParameter("logUID")%>",
                                                logPwd:"<%= request.getParameter("logPwd")%>",
                                                host:"<%= request.getParameter("host")%>",
                                                logFileName:"<%= request.getParameter("logFileName")%>"
                                          },
                                          function(data,status){
                                                $("#thePlace").append(data);
                                                if (data.indexOf(lastUpdate)>-1) {
                                                        binDone = true;
                                                }
                                          });
                                }
                        }
                </script>
        </head>
    <body onLoad='tail2(); setInterval("tail2()", 2000)'>
        <div id="wrapper" class="radius">
                <div id="imageContainer">
                        <img alt="my Image" class="myLogo" src="myLogo.jpg" />
                        <h1>Show Tail Logs</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="navContainer" style="color:white">
                        Logs Update automatically. Please don't press refresh button...
                </div>
                        <div>
                                <div id="thePlace"></div>
                        </div>
                </body>
        </div>
</html>
```

**TailLogServlet.java**

```
package sshUploader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Run several ssh commands in a single JSch session
 */
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Hashtable;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TailLogServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "This servlet tails the remote logs", urlPatterns = { "/TailLogServlet" })
public class TailLogServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TailLogServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try  
        {  
            //System.out.println("*************GETTT TailLogServlet Hit. logFileName :"+request.getParameter("logFileName"));

          PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();  
          response.setContentType("text/html"); 
          response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

          JSch jsch = new JSch();
          String user = request.getParameter("logUID");            //CHANGE ME
          String host = request.getParameter("host");//CHANGE ME
          String passwd = request.getParameter("logPwd");      //CHANGE ME
          int port = 22;    
          Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
          session.setPassword(passwd);

          Hashtable<String, String> hashtable  = new Hashtable<String, String>();
          hashtable.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setConfig(hashtable);

          session.connect();

          Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
          OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
          PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

          channel.connect();
          InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();

           ps.println("tail -f "+request.getParameter("logFileName"));
          ps.close();

          int SIZE = 1024;
          byte[] tmp = new byte[SIZE];
          long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          while ((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)< 3*1000){
             while (input.available() > 0)
             {
                int i = input.read(tmp, 0, SIZE);
                if(i < 0)
                   break;
                 System.out.println(new String(tmp, 0, i)); 
                 pw.println(new String(tmp, 0, i));
             }          
             pw.flush();             
         }


        }catch(Exception e)  
        {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("*************POSTTTTT TailLogServlet Hit. logFileName :"+request.getParameter("logFileName"));
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

The code might have some unwanted imports as I haven't yet done the cleaning.